# Is it possible to use Open Office (import export) filters directly bypassing cumbersome UNO?

Tags: openoffice.org

I would like to use open office to convert to and from MS office. I have been using Open Office's UNO API. The problem with this is that it requires OO to be running in a daemon mode. OO keeps crashing on me and I need to have a dedicated monitoring process to keep OO up.

I was wondering if it would be possible to just extract the filter layer in OO and use this library in my project to do the conversions.

Alternatively is there any command line way of doing doc conversions without having to have the whole OO app running as a server.

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach is to include code that starts the OO server if it is not already running.

However if it is crashing frequently you ought to figure out why.